# Can't detect my external drive

Tags: windows-8, external-hard-drive, osx-mountain-lion

I have a `Buffalo Ministation HD-PCU2` external 500 GB HDD. It's formatted in ex-fat, since I need to use it on my Mac and my PC both. One day I accidentally unplugged it without properly ejecting it from my office pc. And then it started giving me weird issues. In start it sometimes couldn't get detected on some pc and then one day suddenly it stops getting detected on any machine at all. I can't even see the drive letters in Windows (7 and 8 both). I've checked disk management, but no trace of it there too.

I have valuable data in that drive. Any way I can get back the hdd to normal status?

Update:-
I am checking on my Macbook and I can see it in the disk utility, but it shows unmounted and the repair and verify buttons are disabled too.
I can erase the HDD, but I do not want to loose my data. Can anyone suggest any option?

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Open the external chassis and take the hard drive out.  The hard drive inside is either IDE or SATA so, after turning your PC off, connect the hard drive directly to the PC.  Does that work?

Comment: Didn't try that, but I have my laptop, and do not have access to any desktop(Never needed any).

Comment: I try to open the HDD, but it says that if I open it I'll loose my warranty.

Comment: @Creator  Ok no desktop.  You can get a different empty chassis and put it inside there and use USB/esata or whatever your laptop has available.  As far as warranty, it could come down to break the warranty or lose the data.  Ok so you need MAC recovery software.
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download
at the bottom is photorec for MAC. Try that before voiding the warranty.